Create a view in Dynamics where the filter is based on two fields in different tables
I am trying to create a view for Dynamics 365 based on two tables
One Jobs has a field called Currently_Responsible which is a lookup field of systemusers.
The Other ResourcesAllocated is a 1 to many link based on the JobId and also has a field that is a lookup field based on systemeusers.
Now I need to create a view that displays the Jobs whose Currently_Responsible field doesn't match the ResourceAllocated user field.
I can't seem to figure out if it is possible.
Help

it seems to be a strange situation but solvable.
Could you please insert some details about the current structure of the page?
Did you insert a main page with a subform or it's just one page with the fields?
Let us know!
Andrea
